# How to sample the position of many particles?

Tags: density-function, sampling, monte-carlo, sampling-theory

In Density Functional Theory, there are many types of trail variational wave functions. I have a question from the numerical viewpoint: when I have the 1D density functions, and the $N$-dimensional density function is given by some way, for example, by the Slater determinant (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant). Then how to sample the position of particles? Monte-Carlo? Is there an efficient algorithm to do this?